# How to connect to database in Phalcon Framework 3.2.4 using SSL

Tags: php, phalcon-routing, phalcon-orm, phalcon

I am trying to connect to the database in Phalcon Framework 3.2.4 using SSL.
Getting error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev_user'@'XXX.XX.XX.XXX' (using password: YES)

My database/config.php:

```
return new \Phalcon\Config(array(

    'database' => array(
        'adapter' => 'Mysql',
        'host'     => 'xxx.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'username' => 'dev_user',
        'password' => 'XXXXX',
        'dbname'   => 'dev',
        'name'     => 'dev',
        'charset'  => 'utf8')
```

How do I connect to the database using SSL connection in Phalcon? Its not related to credentials since I tried the following and it worked.

```
mysqli_ssl_set($con,NULL,NULL,$pemlocation,NULL,'DHE-RSA-XXXX-SHA');

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,$servername, $username, $password, 
 $dbname))
 {
   die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
```

I referred the documentation link:
https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/1221/connect-through-mysql-with-ssl. But did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, found a solution myself, not sure how works.
I think the array values from app/config/config is passed to app/config/services.php.

```
$di->set('db', function() use ($config) {
 $adapter = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
    "host" => $config->database->host,
    "username" => $config->database->username,
    "password" => $config->database->password,
    "dbname" => $config->database->dbname,
    "charset" => $config->database->charset,
    "options" => [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "/home/ubuntu/YOUR_PEM_FILE_HERE"  ]

    ));
return $adapter;
});
```

And it worked. Hope it helps others who will need to enable an SSL connection to RDS for MySQL.